# Url string match in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here i am trying this code,my url is like this `"http://127.0.0.1/magento21/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvMjEvcHJvZHVjdDIuaHRtbA,,/product/2222/".`

```
var url = settings.url;
if ("url:contains('checkout/cart/add')") {
    alert('sasas');
}
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U cannot just "url:contains('checkout/cart/add')".
In order to check if url contains given pattern. 
U should write code like:

```
if (url.indexOf('checkout/cart/add') >= 0)
```

And it calls string's indexOf to check if it has given substring.

Answer (score 1):

USe this code to find whether url contains a given string:

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento21/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tYWdlbnRvMjEvcHJvZHVjdDIuaHRtbA,,/product/2222/';

if (url.indexOf('checkout/cart/add') > -1)
 {
       alert("your url contains the name string");
    }
```

indexOf find the substring position if it exits in the given string.
Running Demo here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/ykefwudv/)